# Detecting W3WP CPU issues using jetBrains dotTrace

Tags: asp.net, performance, nhibernate, iis, dottrace

Our W3WP process on our production server is constantly high. It doesn't max out at 100% but jumps up into the 90%s a fair bit. To help look into this I profiled the live aplication using JetBrains dotTrace.

The results were as expected. All the slow methods were NHibernate functions that queried our database. My question is, would these slow methods actaully affect the CPU on our web server, as our database server is on a separate machine. Surely if the database server is doing some work then the web server jsut waits for a response, and the CPU shouldn't go up?

If this is the case, how do I use dotTrace (or another tool if neccesary) to work out where the CPU is being used as opposed to the server just waiting for a response from elsewhere?

**dotTrace screenshot of hot spots**
[image]

You can see from the screenshot that most of the time is spend waiting for external HTTP requests to complete. However, these shouldn't affect the CPU usage on the web server I'd have thought

Comment: can you post some relevant screenshots of the dotTrace profile?

Comment: I've added the hotspot screenshot to the question

Comment: Have you solved the problem? What tools have you used to find source of evil?

Answer (score 2):

It may well be NHibernate itself that is doing the hard work on your web server, and that the database is actually doing relatively little.

I would recommend running a SQL profiler to see whether it is really the case that the database is taking a long time on a single call (from NHibernate).

My guess is that you will see NHibernate making lots and lots of calls to the database and then processing them (on your erb server server) and that it is this that is responsible for the high CPU.

If you have a lot of lazy fetching on joins, you can end up in the situation where NHibernate makes many, many calls to the database get the data for one request.

Comment: The database queries return relatively quickly, and I've checked that we are only querying the database when we need to. I'm not suprised that the NHibernate calls are taking the longest, but does it make sense that these match up to the high CPU?